# Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.foo.bar::jar: from/to central (http://): Broken pipe

Tags: maven

While deploying artifact into jfrog, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project : Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com...::jar:1.0.0-14 from/to central (http://artifactory:8080/artifact-release): Broken pipe (Write failed)

Comment: Network/firewall/proxy error ?....

Comment: In my case, it wasn't proxy/network issue and provided the solution in the answers section

Answer (score 2):

1. Verify if the id given in settings.xml and  (in pom.xml) are same

```
<distributionManagement>
           <snapshotRepository>
                <id>**snapshot**</id>
                <name></name>
                <url></url>
            </snapshotRepository>
            <repository>
                <id>**central**</id>
                <name></name>
                <url></url>
            </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

```
<servers>
 <server>
  <id>**snapshot**</id>
  <username></username>
  <password></password>
 </server>
 <server>
  <id>**central**</id>
  <username></username>
  <password></password>
 </server>
</servers>
```

2. User mentioned in settings.xml might not having proper access (in artifactory) to deploy artifact

```
<servers>
 <server>
  <id></id>
  <username>**user**</username>
  <password></password>
 </server>
 <server>
  <id></id>
  <username>**user**</username>
  <password></password>
 </server>
</servers>
```